# Crash starting new activity? (Intent)

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-intent, crash

this is the code of my two activty

this app by the clicking one of the buttons of Activity A, in the Activity B should show a listview with the names specified in the command switch (v.getId ()) in the activity A, and if you click on one of those names should always leave the url below: in the same command of Activity A

But as soon as I click on one of the buttons the app crashes, i don't know how to solve

Activity A

```
 public class GruppiPuntateActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements         OnClickListener {

ArrayList<String> bottone;
Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.gruppipuntate_activity);

    //rimozione action bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button8);
        b9 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button9);
        b10 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button10);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
        b8.setOnClickListener(this);
        b9.setOnClickListener(this);
        b10.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

 }
    //gestione Switch java per selezione puntate
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] product;
        String[] urls;

        Intent episodi = new Intent(GruppiPuntateActivity.this, EpisodiActivity.class);

         switch(v.getId()){ 
         case R.id.button1:
             product = new String[]{"ciao", "1", "bottone"};
             urls = new String[] {"http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x21cxmf_camera-cafe-3-stagione-ep-252-un-cane-per-amico_shortfilms, url2, url3"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", product);
             episodi.putExtra("urls", urls);
             startActivity(episodi);
             break;
         case R.id.button2:
             product = new String[]{"ciao", "1", "bottone"};
             urls = new String[] {"url1, http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x21cxmf_camera-cafe-3-stagione-ep-252-un-cane-per-amico_shortfilms, url3"};
             episodi.putExtra("Product", product);
             episodi.putExtra("urls", urls);
             startActivity(episodi);
             break;
        //etc.etc....
         }
    }
```

}

Activity B

```
  public class EpisodiActivity extends Activity {


String[] episodi = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product");
String[] urls = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");


public class ViewModel {
    private String url;
    private String name;

    public ViewModel(String url, String name) {
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.episodi_activity);

    ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // And in this loop we create the ViewModel instances from 
    // the name and url and add them all to a List
    List<ViewModel> models = new ArrayList<ViewModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < episodi.length; i++) {
        String name = episodi[i];
        String url = urls[i];
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel(name, url);
        models.add(model);
    }


    // Here we create the ArrayAdapter and assign it to the ListView
    // We pass the List of ViewModel instances into the ArrayAdapter
    final ArrayAdapter<ViewModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ViewModel>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, models);

    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);


    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

            // Here we get the ViewModel at the given position
            ViewModel model = (ViewModel) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // And the url from the ViewModel
            String url = model.getUrl();

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: @amarildo  its a Null pointer error

Comment: We maybe need your logcat because there are many reasons for the NullPointerException.

Comment: I need to copy the code? how can I show it to you to see

Comment: Check my answer and if not working please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declarations

```
String[] episodi = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product");
String[] urls = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");
```

Are bad because you are not loading yet the activity to get information from that, you need initialize this variables after, in your onCreate(), onResume or onStart() methods

```
String[] episodi;//Correction
String[] urls;//Correction
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.episodi_activity);
    episodi = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product"); ////Line added
    urls = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");////Line added
    ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
.......
    }
```

Now the best thing that you can do is a validation for this variables

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //creazione fullscreen activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.episodi_activity);
    episodi = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product"); ////Line added
    urls = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");////Line added
    if (episodi == null) { ////Validation
         Log.d("NULL", "episodi is null");
         return;
    }
    if (urls == null) { ////Validation
         Log.d("NULL", "urls is null");
         return;
    ]
    ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
.......
    }
```

Comment: is your code XD, just to the end i put "points" to say "the method is not finished"

Comment: :) this part if (episodi == null) { ////Validation
         Log.d("NULL", "episodi is null");
         return;
    }
    if (urls == null) { ////Validation
         Log.d("NULL", "urls is null");
         return;

Comment: Is in case that you are not passing data in getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product"); or  getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");         if you want comment the //return; is not problem, but if the variables are null your app going to crash

Comment: how can I see if they pass data or not?

Comment: the result is seen in the logcat?

Comment: If I help to you in something, I will be grateful if you give to me a positive valuation. Regards.

Comment: do not worry about the valuation will definitely own :). teamviewer ?, so you give me a hand because I do not understand much :)?

Comment: ok now you put it, however, was not your edit 
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> 11) {// something lie this? now it work with kitkat? yes ok no problem thank bye: bye 
getActionBar. () hide (); 
} 

Multiple markers at this line 
- Requires Call API level 11 (current min is 8): 
android.app.ActionBar # hide 
- Requires Call API level 11 (current min is 8): 
android.app.Activity # getActionBar

Comment: But that validation not going to crash.

Comment: excuse you have 5 more minutes of work team viewer Because only the first url URL CRASH THE OTHER

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
```

all your buttons are initialized only for devices with Api level less than 11

if you click any button on Device with APi level 11 and Above youll get error.

Update :

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
     getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
  // Make Button initialization outside if loop  and your app will work
```

Answer (score 0):

Firts, you should always look in your LogCat, to look what error is thrown.

Second, on your buttons, you have

```
//rimozione action bar
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
    ...
    b1.setOnclickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
}
```

The code runs olny, when the SDK is smaller then 11. Want to function your buttons everytime, so do this

```
//rimozione action bar
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

}
b1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
b2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
...
b1.setOnclickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);
...
```

And then, on the button, zou call setOnClickListener, which allows you to handle click events. But you have to pass a new OnClickListener object, to let it work. look at the official example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents).

In you case, its gonna be like this:

```
b1.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something in response to button click
   }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

put these lines in the onCreate method

```
String[] episodi = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Product");
String[] urls = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");
```